# numbers of zones in an azure availability zone Region

Tags: azure-availability-zones

Is there a way to find out how many zones are then per availability zone Region. does 
 it always 3 zones per availability one? Are there regions where there are more than 3 zones per availability zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you see the regions:

```
az account list-locations -o table
```

According to the cli documentation, it appears there are 3 per region **[--zone {1, 2, 3}] as shown below**, since it enumerates zones 1, 2, and 3 as options when you do an `az vm create` command that would include `--location` and `--zone`

```
az vm create --name
             --resource-group
             [--accelerated-networking {false, true}]
             [--admin-password]
             [--admin-username]
             [--asgs]
             [--assign-identity]
             [--attach-data-disks]
             [--attach-os-disk]
             [--authentication-type {all, password, ssh}]
             [--availability-set]
             [--boot-diagnostics-storage]
             [--computer-name]
             [--custom-data]
             [--data-disk-caching]
             [--data-disk-sizes-gb]
             [--ephemeral-os-disk {false, true}]
             [--generate-ssh-keys]
             [--image]
             [--license-type {None, Windows_Client, Windows_Server}]
             [--location]
             [--nics]
             [--no-wait]
             [--nsg]
             [--nsg-rule {RDP, SSH}]
             [--os-disk-caching {None, ReadOnly, ReadWrite}]
             [--os-disk-name]
             [--os-disk-size-gb]
             [--os-type {linux, windows}]
             [--plan-name]
             [--plan-product]
             [--plan-promotion-code]
             [--plan-publisher]
             [--ppg]
             [--private-ip-address]
             [--public-ip-address]
             [--public-ip-address-allocation {dynamic, static}]
             [--public-ip-address-dns-name]
             [--public-ip-sku {Basic, Standard}]
             [--role]
             [--scope]
             [--secrets]
             [--size]
             [--ssh-dest-key-path]
             [--ssh-key-values]
             [--storage-account]
             [--storage-container-name]
             [--storage-sku]
             [--subnet]
             [--subnet-address-prefix]
             [--subscription]
             [--tags]
             [--ultra-ssd-enabled {false, true}]
             [--use-unmanaged-disk]
             [--validate]
             [--vnet-address-prefix]
             [--vnet-name]
             [--zone {1, 2, 3}]
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cloud?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cloud-list
~